# Can I ask questions about miniatures?

Tags: discussion, questions

I was wondering if there were models/miniatures for certain characters in 40k, but I'm not sure if I can ask about miniatures specifically.

I am aware that asking could possibly be considered a "Where can I get them" question, but I'm not interested in asking that, as it's off topic.

Comment: If you're specifically after miniatures for the WH40K tactical combat game people play at Games Workshop stores on elaborate terrain tables, that may be more at home on [boardgames.se]. The Warhammer 40K tabletop RPGs are totally on topic here though, as are questions about miniatures related to them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Asking about miniatures is totally on-topic for RPG.SE.

**However**, for *Warhammer 40,000* miniatures specifically, you can find *way* more experts in [boargames.SE's [warhammer-40k] tag](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k) than you will ever find here at RPG.SE.

So it's on-topic, yes. But we're probably not the droids you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

We have a [miniatures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miniatures) tag with nearly 40 questions! So long as you're meeting all the other guidelines for questions, miniatures and models (as RPG props/tools, not as collectibles or for wargaming) are totally on topic.